# Problem forking fork() multiple processes Unix

Tags: c, process, fork

So I have this function that forks N number of child processes.  However it seems to be forking more than specified. Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks

```
void forkChildren(int nChildren){
    int i;
    for(i = 1; i <= nChildren; i++){
        pid = fork();
        if(pid == 0)          
            printf("I'm a child: %d PID: %d\n",i, getpid());
    }

}
```

In main I call:

```
forkChildren(5);
```

I am expecting the following output:

```
I'm a child: 1 PID: 2990
I'm a child: 2 PID: 2991
I'm a child: 3 PID: 2992
I'm a child: 4 PID: 2993
I'm a child: 5 PID: 2994
```

But instead I get the following:

```
I'm a child: 1 PID: 2990
I'm a child: 2 PID: 2991
I'm a child: 3 PID: 2992
I'm a child: 4 PID: 2993
I'm a child: 5 PID: 2994
user@computer:~/directory/$ I'm a child: 2 PID: 2999
I'm a child: 3 PID: 3000
I'm a child: 3 PID: 3001
I'm a child: 4 PID: 3002
I'm a child: 5 PID: 3003
I'm a child: 5 PID: 3004
I'm a child: 4 PID: 3005
I'm a child: 5 PID: 3006
I'm a child: 4 PID: 3007
I'm a child: 5 PID: 3008
I'm a child: 3 PID: 3011
I'm a child: 4 PID: 3012
I'm a child: 4 PID: 3010
I'm a child: 5 PID: 3013
I'm a child: 5 PID: 3014
I'm a child: 5 PID: 3015
I'm a child: 4 PID: 3018
I'm a child: 5 PID: 3019
I'm a child: 5 PID: 3020
I'm a child: 5 PID: 3021
I'm a child: 5 PID: 3023
I'm a child: 5 PID: 3025
I'm a child: 5 PID: 3024
I'm a child: 4 PID: 3022
I'm a child: 5 PID: 3026
I'm a child: 5 PID: 3027
```

Comment: I see now. I just put exit(0); after each child prints its info.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The fork() call spawns a new process which begins its execution *at the exact same point* where the fork occurred.  So, it looks like fork "returns twice"

What's happening here is that your fork() call returns twice, so both the parent and child process continue looping and spawning new processes.  Each child (of both the original parent and child) then forks again, repeatedly doubling the number of processes...

Comment: Not quite doubling. The children are still incrementing i in the loop so each of the second generation will only create four grandchildren, *not* 5. It's some form of factorial. But, other than that *minor* nitpick, good answer.

Comment: @paxdiablo: The child does increment i, but only its local copy. It has no effect on parent's copy of i.

Answer (score 15):

When you `fork` a process, you basically end up with two (almost) exact copies of the process and both of them will continue running.

So what's happening is that the children themselves are continuing the loop in the own process space (after they print their output) *as well* as the parent doing it. And, in fact, because these children are also forking, the grandchildren will also carry on from that point. I'm sure there's a formula for actually figuring out how many children you end up with (probably something like N!) but I don't have the energy to figure it out at the moment. Better to use the following solution.

The way to tell the difference between parent and child is the return value from `fork`.

- If you get back a -1, you're the parent and the `fork` failed.
- If you get back a zero, you're the child.
- If you get back a positive number, you're the parent and that number is the child PID (so you can manipulate it or `wait` for it).

Here's some test code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void forkChildren (int nChildren) {
    int i;
    pid_t pid;
    for (i = 1; i <= nChildren; i++) {
        pid = fork();
        if (pid == -1) {
            /* error handling here, if needed */
            return;
        }
        if (pid == 0) {
            printf("I am a child: %d PID: %d\n",i, getpid());
            sleep (5);
            return;
        }
    }
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc < 2) {
        forkChildren (2);
    } else {
        forkChildren (atoi (argv[1]));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and some output to show you what's happening:

```
pax> forktest 5
I am a child: 1 PID: 4188
I am a child: 2 PID: 4180
I am a child: 3 PID: 5396
I am a child: 4 PID: 4316
I am a child: 5 PID: 4260

pax> _
```

Comment: I'm helping a friend with an OS assignment and the above function works fine, thanx!

Answer (score 1):

Each child process picks up and continues the loop.

In other words, child 1 is spawned and continues with iteration #2 of loop etc.

When a process is forked, a copy of the current process is made: the resulting child process continues execution after the fork() call. That's why you must take care of the return code in your logic.

Answer (score 1):

In this exercise I'd use recursion rather than a for loop. This way you can have the fork() instruction called multiple times but just on one of the two copies of the process. You can make the child process spawn another child process, thus having grandparents, grand-grandparents etc. or you can call the fork() on the parent side, having a single "father" and multiple children. This is a sample of code which implements the latter solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int nChildren;

void myFork(int n);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  // just a check on the number of arguments supplied
  if (argc < 2) {
    printf("Usage: forktest <number_of_children>\n");
    printf("Example: forktest 5 - spawns 5 children processes\n");
    return -1;
  }

  nChildren = atoi(argv[1]);
  // starting the recursion...
  myFork(nChildren-1);
  return 0;
}

// the recursive function
void myFork(int n) {
  pid_t pid;

  pid = fork();

  // the child does nothing but printing a message on screen
  if (pid == 0) {
    printf("I am a child: %d PID: %d\n", nChildren-n, getpid());
    return;
  }

  // if pid != 0, we're in the parent
  // let's print a message showing that the parent pid is always the same...
  printf("It's always me (PID %d) spawning a new child (PID %d)\n", getpid(), pid);
  // ...and wait for the child to terminate.
  wait(pid);

  // let's call ourself again, decreasing the counter, until it reaches 0.
  if (n > 0) {
    myFork(n-1);
  }
}
```